# How to import third party component in blade file while using vue?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I already install select2 component via npm, but im unable to import in my blade file

```
@push('js')
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
    <script type="module">
        import Select2 from '/node_modules/vue3-select2-component';

        Vue.createApp({}).mount('#app')
    </script>
@endpush
```

The folder is locate in myproject/node_modules/vue3-select2-component

but im keep getting ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

You need to register component like below.

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
let app = createApp({});
app.component("select2", require("./node_modules/vue3-select2-component").default);
app.mount("#app");
```